# Text classification app

Tags: open-source, nlp, machine-learning, neural-network

I want to classify some text files into one of two "buckets". I've seen a lot of libraries to do this but I haven't been able to find anything already packaged into an app.

I want to be able to feed the app labeled data and/or label data the app/model is unsure of, until it is sufficiently accurate that I can feed it unlabelled data and get it to attach labels/filter out one of the two buckets. Either GUI or command line is fine, assuming the documentation is good.

It would be nice if the app in question was open source or at least had a way to export the model to a well used/documented format, so the training wouldn't be locked in to this particular app.